# DateTime Current Month in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Quite a noob question but I am confused as to how to simplify this code and make it efficient too.

I am trying to get the previous 3 months from the CURRENT month rather than the month from the current day (DateTime.Today)

Here is my code:

```
public int NumberTicketsThreeMonthsAgo
{
    get { return AllTickets.Count(t => DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3) < t.CreateDateTime); }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. How would the *current* month be different than the month from the *current* day?

Comment: Set the `Day` to `1` maybe?

Comment: I think so what you meant is: say Today is 22nd Oct then you want 1st July which is 3 months past excluding current month. is it right?

Comment: Do you mean you want, for example, all tickets from august/september/october? So from start of 3rd month ago?

Comment: Thanks guys! Honestly, I sort of wanted all the tickets from the end (better the 28th to avoid issues with leap years) of the month. I figured out from the answers below that I needed a variable within get to do that for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give the right logic:

```
public int NumberTicketsThreeMonthsAgo
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month,
                                        1).AddMonths(-3);
    get { return AllTickets.Count(t => dt < t.CreateDateTime); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) this answered my question and explained what I needed to do as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int NumberTicketsThreeMonthsAgo
{
    get 
    {
        var earliestDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 
                                        DateTime.Today.Month,
                                        1).AddMonths(-3);
        return AllTickets.Count(t => earliestDate < t.CreateDateTime); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int NumberTicketsThreeMonthsAgo
{
    get { AllTickets.Count(t => t > new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-3)); }
}
```

Comment: Do test that with a date in January. All months are `> -2`

Comment: This is true, will Modify to use DateTime.AddMonths(-3)

Answer (score 0):

I would store your new date as a variable and pass it in, instead of evaluating it multiple times and also change this from a property to a method

```
public int NumberTicketsThreeMonthsAgo(IEnumerable<Ticket> tickets)
{
    var startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(-3);
    return tickets.Count(t => startDate < t.CreateDateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a similar functionality as `DateTime.Today`, but a method that returns the 1st day of a given `DateTime`. You can use this [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static DateTime MonthDayOne(this DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
}
```

Now this works and returns the first of july:

```
DateTime threeMonthsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).MonthDayOne();
```

Comment: `AddMonths(-3).MonthDayOne()` and `MonthDayOne().AddMonths(-3)` could be subtly different and then the 2nd form seems more sensible. Also, `Now` is less appropriate than `Today`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: i don't understand both doubts. The method itself is what OP has asked. The way how i use it is not related to how to get the first day of a given month. I have used `Now` to demonstrate that the time doesn't matter to emphasize the similarity to `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: Yeah, DateTime will clip 30 February. Spooky, but it makes the 2 calls the same. But that you use `Now` to make a point is easily lost, in real life this would simply be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 public int NumberTicketsThreeMonthsAgo
 {
     get 
     {
         new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(-3)
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand clearly but i think it's what u want,

```
MessageBox.Show("" + System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).Month);
```

Comment: Not sure how this got upvoted because it's wrong in many ways.